# Assign value to dataframe from another dataframe based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to assign values from a column in df2['values'] to a column df1['values']. However values should only be assigned if:

1. df2['category'] is equal to the df1['category'] (rows are part of the same category)
2. df1['date'] is in df2['date_range'] (date is in a certain range for a specific category)

So far I have this code, which works, but is far from efficient, since it takes me two days to process the two dfs (df1 has ca. 700k rows).

```
for i in df1.category.unique():
for j in df2.category.unique():
    if i == j: # matching categories
        for ia, ra in df1.loc[df1['category'] == i].iterrows():
            for ib, rb in df2.loc[df2['category'] == j].iterrows():
                if df1['date'][ia] in df2['date_range'][ib]:
                    df1.loc[ia, 'values'] = rb['values']
                    break
```

I read that I should try to avoid using for-loops when working with dataframes. List comprehensions are great, however since I do not have a lot of experience yet, I struggle formulating more complicated code.

How can I iterate over this problem more efficient? What essential key aspect should I think about when iterating over dataframes with conditions?

The code above tends to skip some rows or assigns them wrongly, so I need to do a cleanup afterwards. And the biggest problem, that it is really slow.

Thank you.

Some df1 insight:

```
df1.head()

    date                          category
0  2015-01-07                       f2
1  2015-01-26                       f2
2  2015-01-26                       f2
3  2015-04-08                       f2
4  2015-04-10                       f2
```

Some df2 insight:

```
df2.date_range[0]

DatetimeIndex(['2011-11-02', '2011-11-03', '2011-11-04', '2011-11-05',
               '2011-11-06', '2011-11-07', '2011-11-08', '2011-11-09',
               '2011-11-10', '2011-11-11', '2011-11-12', '2011-11-13',
               '2011-11-14', '2011-11-15', '2011-11-16', '2011-11-17',
               '2011-11-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

df2 other two columns:

```
df2[['values','category']].head()

            values             category
0            01                  f1
1            02                  f1
2           2.1                  f1
3           2.2                  f1
4            03                  f1
```

Comment: Can you expand on what `"date"` and `"date_range"` look like, what types they are and how they are formatted ?

Comment: can you show some sample data

Comment: @NaturalFrequency I have added some data samples from both dataframes

Comment: @aws_apprentice I have added some data samples from both dataframes

Comment: so each row for `df2['date_range']` is a list?

Comment: @aws_apprentice ```type(df2.date_range[0])``` says ```pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex```. If it helps, this column was created with ```df2['date_range'] = df2[['startdate', 'enddate']].apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)```, where startdate and enddate are type ```datetime.date```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Corrected erroneous code and added OP input from a comment

Alright so if you want to join the dataframes on similar categories, you can `merge` them :

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = "category")
```

Next, since `date` is a timestamp and the "date_range" is actually generated from two columns, per OP's comment, we rather use :

```
mask = (df3["startdate"] <= df3["date"]) & (df3["date"] <= df3["enddate"])

subset = df3.loc[mask]
```

Now we get back to `df1` and merge on the common dates while keeping all the values from `df1`. This will create `NaN` for the subset values where they didn't match with `df1` in the earlier merge.

As such, we set `df1["values"]` where the entries in common are not `NaN` and we leave them be otherwise.

```
common_dates = df1.merge(subset, on = "date", how= "left") # keeping df1 values

df1["values"] = np.where(common_dates["values_y"].notna(), 
                         common_dates["values_y"], df1["values"])
```

N.B : If more than one `df1["date"]` matches with the date range, you'll have to drop some values otherwise duplicates mess up the explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately I am receiving the following TypeError ```'(Int64Index([], dtype='int64'), 'values_y')' is an invalid key ``` since ```cond_idx``` is type ```pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index```.

Comment: @Audiogott I need to see more explanations this does not mess up my indexing. Are the columns you use named the same as mine ? What version of ``pandas`` are you using ?

Comment: My `pandas` version is `0.25.1`. The column names in my case are slightly different, however I have adjusted them accordingly, so this shouldn't be the problem

Comment: It seems like the error comes from the ``index`` being empty actually, not from the type. It's because of ``isin`` which I messed up

Comment: What is it that you messed up?

Comment: ``isin`` is not appropriate for this usage, I'm gonna re-write my answer

Comment: @Audiogott the problem should be fixed, note that the first merge can generate a very large dataframe and also that you should rather keep the "startdate" and "enddate" columns. Indexes are not meant to be in column cells like that

Comment: @Audiogott would you mind telling me if that worked?

Answer (score -1):

You could accomplish the first point:

*1. df2['category'] is equal to the df1['category']*

with the use of a join.

You could then use a for loop for filtering the data poings from df1[date] inside the merged dataframe that are not contemplated in the df2[date_range]. Unfortunately I need more information about the content of df1[date] and df2[date_range] to write the code here that would exactly do that.

Comment: while this would be part of the approach you go with, currently this does not qualify as an answer, please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) what constitutes a good answer

Comment: I just explained why I downvoted you and linked to what a good answer entails, given that OP has not provided sample data it is hard to answer the question until he does. the answer you posted qualifies more as a comment than anything

Comment: @AnaPreciado I have added some data samples from both dataframes